# 'Incompatible type' error in emitting a String array in an Observable in RxJava 2

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java2, reactivex

Asking a very basic RxJava question here because I couldn't find it anywhere else.

I'm having this Observable in RxJava 2 -

```
Observable<String> database = Observable.just("1", "2", "3");
```

It works fine. No problems.

But when I try to pass an array like this -

```
arr = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
Observable<String> database = Observable.just(arr);
```

It throws an error for **incompatible types**.

1. Isn't the second declaration same thing as the first declaration? If not, why?
2. I need a way to emit a predefined Array and on onNext of the Observer, I should be getting the individual items of the Array. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't the second declaration same thing as the first declaration? If not, why?

No. The type system of Java makes a distinction between plain types and an array of those types:

```
String s = new String("whatever")

String z = new String[0]; // <--------- compile error
```

A `String[]` is not a single `String` type.

The method `just` is defined as follows:

```
Observable<T> just(T item);
```

If we substitute `T = String`, you'll get a signature of `Observable<String> just(String item)`.

If we substitute `T = String[]`, what do we get? `Observable<String[]> just(String[] item)`.

> I need a way to emit a predefined Array and on onNext of the Observer, I should be getting the individual items of the Array. How to achieve that?

Use `fromArray` as it is defined as `Observable<T> fromArray(T[] array)`:

```
Observable<String> database = Observable.fromArray(arr);
```